# Ereg_replace with a String

Tags: regex, ereg-replace

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "{gfgd}i:123;a:7:{gfgd}i:5;a:35:";
```

And I want to replace it to:

```
$str = "{gfgd},{gfgd},";
```

I want to use ereg_replace with it and replace this kind of phrase:

"i:[0-9]a:[0-9]:"  into   "," sign.

I try it:

```
     $str = "i:143;a:5:{gfgd}i:123;a:7:{gfgd}i:5;a:35:";  
     $text = ereg_replace("/^i:[0-9]+;a:[0-9]+:+$", ",", $str);
```

But i doesn't work. Can you help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "i:143;a:5:{gfgd}i:123;a:7{gfgd}i:5;a:35";  
$str = ereg_replace("\}[^\{]+\{", "},{", $str); // replace between } and { with },{
$str = ereg_replace("^[^\{]+", "", $str); // remove from first
$str = ereg_replace("[^\}]+$", ",", $str); // remove from last 
print $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `ereg_replace` as `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0`**

Use `preg_replace` instead and your regex is wrong. Remove anchors `^ and $`

```
$text = preg_replace('/i:[0-9]+;a:[0-9]+:?/', ",", $str);
//=> ,{gfgd},{gfgd},
```

**Online Demo: http://ideone.com/W2P55n**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are dealing with a PHP array or object serialized into string. I recommend running:

```
<?php
    $arrayOrObject = unserialize($theEntireStringYouGot);
    print_r($arrayOrObject);
?>
```

That way you may not need to even deal with regex at all.

Note: it will not unserialize a piece of string like in your example, feed it the whole thing.

Comment: ok, thanks - unserialize works perfect,  but if i would like use it in javascript ?

Comment: Use json_encode to serialize your array in PHP into JSON and then decode JSON in JavaScript. There is JSON2 library that you can use for that unless you are using jQuery or like that has it built in.